# Automate VPN with Two Factor Auth

Tags: vpn, two-factor-authentication

We use a VPN client that takes a google auth code as password. Due to industry regulations for payment cards we need to re-auth every 30 minutes. This is an interruption to work flow and I am wondering if anyone has recommendations on how to automate re-authing the VPN client once already logged in to Authy.

We use Authy desktop / Chrome extension for auth code retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done if you use an API for Authy and have the TOTP seeds that are used in Authy. To implement this in a VPN, a separate application must be made with the API implemented, to automatically authenticate your VPN.

Also, exclusively using a TOTP is not safe for critical work. If the seed is stolen, then the VPN is compromised. You should consider implementing a password as well as the TOTP, to create a 2FA scheme. If you are sysadmin, you should look for an API (a quick search on Google should provide), and add it to your VPN client. If you aren't sysadmin, you should inquire your sysadmin or a representative if a method is possible.